# Using javascript fullscreen or jquery fullscreen lib on window.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a cbt project and i want the application to be fullscreen on load of the application. so am using the jquery fullscreen libirary. and it only fires at the click of the button. i have tried my best but can't get it to work.Code below

```
$(function () {

 //Full Screen work out!
 window.addEventListener('load', $(document).bind("fullscreenchange", function(e) {
       console.log("Full screen changed.");

    }));
    $(document).bind("fullscreenchange", function(e) {
       console.log("Full screen changed.");

    });

    $(document).bind("fullscreenerror", function(e) {
       console.log("Full screen error.");
       $("#status").text("Browser won't enter full screen mode for some reason.");
    });

 });
```

below is the Libirary

```
/**
 * @preserve jquery.fullscreen 1.1.5
 * https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin
 * Copyright (C) 2012-2013 Klaus Reimer <k@ailis.de>
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 * (See http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license)
 */

(function(jQuery) {

/**
 * Sets or gets the fullscreen state.
 * 
 * @param {boolean=} state
 *            True to enable fullscreen mode, false to disable it. If not
 *            specified then the current fullscreen state is returned.
 * @return {boolean|Element|jQuery|null}
 *            When querying the fullscreen state then the current fullscreen
 *            element (or true if browser doesn't support it) is returned
 *            when browser is currently in full screen mode. False is returned
 *            if browser is not in full screen mode. Null is returned if 
 *            browser doesn't support fullscreen mode at all. When setting 
 *            the fullscreen state then the current jQuery selection is 
 *            returned for chaining.
 * @this {jQuery}
 */
function fullScreen(state)
{
    var e, func, doc;

    // Do nothing when nothing was selected
    if (!this.length) return this;

    // We only use the first selected element because it doesn't make sense
    // to fullscreen multiple elements.
    e = (/** @type {Element} */ this[0]);

    // Find the real element and the document (Depends on whether the
    // document itself or a HTML element was selected)
    if (e.ownerDocument)
    {
        doc = e.ownerDocument;
    }
    else
    {
        doc = e;
        e = doc.documentElement;
    }

    // When no state was specified then return the current state.
    if (state == null)
    {
        // When fullscreen mode is not supported then return null
        if (!((/** @type {?Function} */ doc["exitFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["webkitExitFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["webkitCancelFullScreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["msExitFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["mozCancelFullScreen"])))
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Check fullscreen state
        state = !!doc["fullscreenElement"]
            || !!doc["msFullscreenElement"]
            || !!doc["webkitIsFullScreen"]
            || !!doc["mozFullScreen"];
        if (!state) return state;

        // Return current fullscreen element or "true" if browser doesn't
        // support this
        return (/** @type {?Element} */ doc["fullscreenElement"])
            || (/** @type {?Element} */ doc["webkitFullscreenElement"])
            || (/** @type {?Element} */ doc["webkitCurrentFullScreenElement"])
            || (/** @type {?Element} */ doc["msFullscreenElement"])
            || (/** @type {?Element} */ doc["mozFullScreenElement"])
            || state;
    }

    // When state was specified then enter or exit fullscreen mode.
    if (state)
    {
        // Enter fullscreen
        func = (/** @type {?Function} */ e["requestFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ e["webkitRequestFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ e["webkitRequestFullScreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ e["msRequestFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ e["mozRequestFullScreen"]);
        if (func) 
        {
            func.call(e);
        }
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        // Exit fullscreen
        func = (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["exitFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["webkitExitFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["webkitCancelFullScreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["msExitFullscreen"])
            || (/** @type {?Function} */ doc["mozCancelFullScreen"]);
        if (func) func.call(doc);
        return this;
    }
}

/**
 * Toggles the fullscreen mode.
 * 
 * @return {!jQuery}
 *            The jQuery selection for chaining.
 * @this {jQuery}
 */
function toggleFullScreen()
{
    return (/** @type {!jQuery} */ fullScreen.call(this, 
        !fullScreen.call(this)));
}

/**
 * Handles the browser-specific fullscreenchange event and triggers
 * a jquery event for it.
 *
 * @param {?Event} event
 *            The fullscreenchange event.
 */
function fullScreenChangeHandler(event)
{
    jQuery(document).trigger(new jQuery.Event("fullscreenchange"));
}

/**
 * Handles the browser-specific fullscreenerror event and triggers
 * a jquery event for it.
 *
 * @param {?Event} event
 *            The fullscreenerror event.
 */
function fullScreenErrorHandler(event)
{
    jQuery(document).trigger(new jQuery.Event("fullscreenerror"));
}

/**
 * Installs the fullscreenchange event handler.
 */
function installFullScreenHandlers()
{
    var e, change, error;

    // Determine event name
    e = document;
    if (e["webkitCancelFullScreen"])
    {
        change = "webkitfullscreenchange";
        error = "webkitfullscreenerror";
    }
    else if (e["msExitFullscreen"])
    {
        change = "MSFullscreenChange";
        error = "MSFullscreenError";
    }
    else if (e["mozCancelFullScreen"])
    {
        change = "mozfullscreenchange";
        error = "mozfullscreenerror";
    }
    else 
    {
        change = "fullscreenchange";
        error = "fullscreenerror";
    }

    // Install the event handlers
    jQuery(document).bind(change, fullScreenChangeHandler);
    jQuery(document).bind(error, fullScreenErrorHandler);
}

jQuery.fn["fullScreen"] = fullScreen;
jQuery.fn["toggleFullScreen"] = toggleFullScreen;
installFullScreenHandlers();

})(jQuery);
```

just want to trigger it at start of the examination 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen is bounded to user interractions, it cannot be done on windows load, it gives the user the options to either toggle fullscreen or exit fullscreen